# Deploy Gollum wiki with Engine Yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, icu, engineyard, gollum-wiki

Gollum is "A simple, Git-powered wiki with a sweet API and local frontend."
It's hosted on GitHub: http://github.com/github/gollum

Deploying my site to EngineYard is generating this error.

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Installing charlock_holmes (0.6.9.4)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

It seems to be an issue with installing an dependency called 'ICU'.
I've installed ICU using the 'install unix package' button on the EngineYard dashboard but can't seem to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the charlock_holmes gem working you need to pass a number of flags using bundle config.

Run the following from the command line within the project folder:

```
$ bundle config --local build.charlock_holmes --with-ldflags='-L. -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--no-undefined -lz -licuuc'
```

Commit the newly created file (/.bundle/config) to version control and redeploy.

This solution based largly on advice I received from Engine Yard support who also referenced from within the projects github issues.
https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes/issues/32#issuecomment-17033186

Answer (score 1):

I see you've just submitted this issue as support ticket to us at Engine Yard support, so this issue shall be picked up by a support engineer shortly and responded to.

Thanks,

Paul.